# Why does hibernate permit the update of a parent table although update="false" is provided to the many-to-one relationship?

Tags: hibernate, parent-child

I created a simple case for testing and I don't get the expected behavior. 
**I am interested why hibernate chooses to update the parent table (Country) although I provide update="false" attribute to the many-to-one relationship (in the Address.hbm.xml)?**

The DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
  `id` smallint NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
CREATE TABLE Address (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `firstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `countryId` smallint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (countryId)
   REFERENCES Country(id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

The hibernate xmls:

```
<class name="Country" table="Country" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string" not-null="true" length="100"/>
</class>
<class name="Address" table="Address" >
    <id name="id" column="id" type="long" unsaved-value="-1">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="addressFirstName" column="firstName" type="string" not-null="true" length="100"/>
    <property name="addressLastName" column="lastName" type="string" not-null="true" length="100"/>
    <!-- Country is parent table, Address is child table (holds the FK countryId).
        From MySQL:
        CASCADE: Update the row from the parent table and automatically update the matching rows in the child table.
        RESTRICT: Rejects the delete operation for the parent table.
        From hibernate:
        1. cascade (optional): specifies which operations should be cascaded from the parent object to the associated object.
        2. update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the mapped columns should be included in SQL UPDATE 
        and/or INSERT statements. Setting both to false allows a pure "derived" association whose value is initialized 
        from another property that maps to the same column(s), or by a trigger or other application.
     -->
    <many-to-one name="country" class="Country" column="countryId" 
        not-null="true" cascade="persist,merge,save-update"  update="false" />
    <many-to-one name="state" class="State" column="stateId" 
        cascade="persist,merge,save-update" update="false" />
</class>
```

My Country table has one row (id=1):

```
INSERT INTO Country (name) VALUES ("United States");
```

If I do following:

```
Country country = getCountryFrom("US");
Address address = new Address();
address.setAddressFirstName("Deksa");
address.setAddressLastName("Jakim");
country.setName("Slovenia");
address.setCountry(country);
address.setId(-1);
saveAddress(address);
session.saveOrUpdate(address);
```

I expect that I have one new row inserted in the Address table, but I also get an update on the Country table - the only row, the name of the country becomes Slovenia, instead of staying United States (expected behavior <= update="false"):

```
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id6_, country0_.name as name6_ from Country country0_ where country0_.stringId='US'
Hibernate: insert into Address (firstName, lastName, countryId) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update Country set name=? where id=?
```

**So why does hibernate update the parent table when instructed not to?**

Kind regards,
Despot

Edit: Shortly after writing this post I realized that I am confusing the DB's cascade with the hibernate's cascade and that solved all my problems.
The thing is the following: Hibernate clearly says:

> update, insert (optional - defaults to
>   true): specifies that the mapped
>   columns should be included in SQL
>   UPDATE  and/or INSERT statements.
>   Setting both to false allows a pure
>   "derived" association whose value is
>   initialized from another property that
>   maps to the same column(s), or by a
>   trigger or other application.

. This means that when using update="false" on the country property (on the countryId), I say to hibernate you cannot do UPDATE Address SET firstName="x", lastName="y", **countryId=123** where condition; Only do an update without the countryId.
Than I saw that the DB's ON UPDATE CASCADE refers to the parent table (Country) - if the Country was updated, than update the child table (the countryId column in Address table). Contrary to what I thought hibernate's update would do, I realized that by providing cascade="save-update", I say to hibebernate, whatever values you have for the Country object in the Address object update them in it's own Country table. So the solution was to have cascade="persist,merge" without the save-update part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `update = "false"` on `country` property doesn't allow you to update the corresponding `countryId` field, i.e. to choose another `Country` for particular `Address`.

If you want to disable chaning of the name of existing `Country`, you need to specify `update = "false"` on the corresponding property:

```
<class name="Country" table="Country" lazy="false"> 
    ...
    <property name="name" type="string" not-null="true" length="100" update = "false" /> 
</class>
```

Comment: I wanted to disallow updating of the Country (child object), not disallow a child object's property. In your case, if I have another Class (for example Continent), that has the Country as a child/member object, and if I wanted to allow this parent class (Continent) to update the Country, it wouldn't be possible. In other words I think this way you will disable the updating of the Country's name property from everywhere which is not what I want.  Anyways thanks for the reply!